# Non-vanishing of generalized minors on T-stable unipotent subgroups

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, cluster-algebras

Let $G$ be a complex simply connected algebraic group, $T$ a maximal torus of $G$ and $B$, $B^-$ Borel subgroups which are opposite with respect to $T$ and let $U$ (resp. $U^-$) be the unipotent radical of $B$ (resp. $B^-$). Following Berenstein, Fomin and Zelevinsky, (see [Bouble Brhuat cells and total positivity](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9802056.pdf) for more details) for any fundamental weight $\varpi$ of $G$ and $v, w \in W$ we have a function $\Delta_{v\varpi, w\varpi} \in \mathbb{C}[G]$, these functions are generally called generalized minors.

For any $x \in W$ we define (with little abuse of notation):
$$  U (x) := U \cap x^{-1} U^- x$$.

I would like to know for which $\varpi, v, w , x$ the generalized minor $\Delta_{v\varpi, w\varpi}$ does not vanish on $U(x)$. So from now on suppose that $\varpi, v, w , x$ are fixed, and call $\alpha$ the simple root such that $\langle \varpi , \alpha^\vee \rangle$=1.

Just to make some example, $\Delta_{s_\alpha \varpi, \varpi}$ vanishes on $U=U(w_0)$, while for any $w \in W$ $\Delta_{\varpi, w\varpi}$ doesn't vanish on $U$.

We know that the zero locus of $\Delta_{v\varpi, w\varpi}$ on $G$ is the closure of $vB^-s_\alpha B w^{-1}$, to me it's not clear if this can help. Another general feature is the following: consider $V(\varpi)$ the irreducible $G$-representation of highest weight $\varpi$, let $y_v$ (resp. $y_w$) be nonzero weight vectors of $V(\varpi)$ of weight $v\varpi$ (resp. $w \varpi$). Then   $\Delta_{v\varpi, w\varpi}$ doesn't vanish on $U(x)$ if and only if the linear span of $U(x)y_w$ contains  $y_v$.

From Theorem 2.22 of [Double Brhuat cells and total positivity](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9802056.pdf) we can deduce that for $ v \leq w \leq x^{-1}$ (the notation $v \leq w$ means that $l(w)=l(v) + l(v^{-1}w)$ where $l$ is the length function) the generalize minor $\Delta_{v\varpi, w \varpi}$ does not vanish on $U(x)$, nevertheless this condition is sufficient but not necessray, for instace if $G=\mathrm{SL}_3$, $v:=s_1=(1,2)$ $w:= s_2s_1=(1,3,2)$, $x=w^{-1}$, then $$U(x)= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & *\\
0 & 1 &* \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

and $\Delta_{v\varpi_1, w\varpi_1}$ is just the function that sends a matrix to its $(2,3)$-entry. Clearly it doesn't vanish on $U(x)$ even if w're not in the situation described above.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem? To be more preciese does anybody know a condition on $\varpi$,$v,w,x$ which is equivqlent to the nonvanishing of the corresponding generalized minor on $U(x)$. Thank you very much.